# How to "press" enter in interactive mode in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs

I would like to press enter in my Elisp script when I am in a REPL window.

but `(newline)` just moves the cursor to the next line and not simulate the press of the Enter key on my keyboard.

Is there a function in Emacs Lisp that works in Emacs interactive mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emacs, depending on the mode you are, the same key may have different definitions (that is, it may be bound to different commands). The best way to simulate a key press is to get exactly which function is bound to that key. You can do that with `lookup-key`. This function will return a *function* that is bound to whatever key you look up. To execute the function, use `funcall`:

```lisp
(funcall (lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "RET")))
```

The function `current-local-map` returns the key map for whatever context you are in. You can use other maps depending on what you want, such as `current-global-map`.